# Buttons isn't setting value

Tags: java, android, user-interface

Im brand new to android and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. The current code looks like:

```
public class TypeActivity extends Activity {
    private boolean alcoholin = false;
...
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search_type);

        alcohol = (Button) findViewById(R.id.alcohol_button);
...
alcohol.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                alcoholin=true;
                Intent i = new Intent (TypeActivity.this,ingredients.class);
                startActivity(i);


            }
        });
...
public boolean getalcholin(){
        return alcoholin;
    }
```

This code is then supposed to set a value in another class. I have tested the code and I know that if i state the the boolean is true in the beginning of my code, then I will make the other code's boolean equal true. However, if I try to set the value when the user presses the button the value does not get updated.

Please help!

Comment: Can you show how you are trying to change the value in the other class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Android the standard way to send data from one Activity to another is by specifying "extras" on the Intent that you use to start a new activity.

You are already using an Intent in your onClick method to start your "ingredients" activity (Your code would be more readable if you named your activity something like IngredientsActivity instead) - you just need to add some "extras" to it.

Please read up on the training tutorial [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html), but without knowing what your ultimate goal is you probably want something like:

```
alcohol.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) { 
        Intent i = new Intent (TypeActivity.this,IngredientsActivity.class);
        i.putExtra(IngredientsActivity.EXTRA_INGREDIENT_TYPE, "alcohol");
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

... and then in IngredientsActivity you would have something like:

```
public static final String EXTRA_INGREDIENT_TYPE = "ingredient";

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ingredients);

        String ingredientType = getIntent().getStringExtra(IngredientsActivity.EXTRA_INGREDIENT_TYPE);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This would never work because alcoholin would **NOT** exist as this is an entirely different Activity. Why don't you instead use the Extras of the intent to pass data between the two Activities.

### Standards

Class names should always have each word capitalized like MyClassObject in java.

Comment: What do you mean? how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Excercise your google fu and search "Android Intent Extras" I'm sure you'll find something. Also you should read the android fundamentals to learn what is an Activity and how intent works.